# Wordpress inside Rails subfolder: how to set blog root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, .htaccess, url-routing, reverse-proxy

Inspired by [that great article](https://hackernoon.com/wordpress-inside-a-ruby-on-rails-app-c324fbf39ad8) from **Paul Arterburn** and forced by my client SEO needs, I have setup a Wordpress blog hosted by [WPEngine](https://wpengine.com/) to work inside a subdirectory of a Ruby-on-Rails app hosted by [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

## Description of the problem

**The problem is that relative URLs doesn't match the blog URL**. For example when I create a link like `<a href="/">Should be https://www.example.com/blog/</a>`, the webpage display the link as `https://www.example.com`. Not cool.

Strange enough, the rest of the links seems to be fine.

- A category: https://www.example.com/blog/categories/some-category
- An article: https://www.example.com/blog/some-category/my-great-post

Something else could help to solve that problem. We are using the extension [AMPforWP](https://ampforwp.com/). When we add `/amp` to the post URL, *eg* `https://www.example.com/blog/some-category/my-great-post/amp` it become `https://example.wpengine.com/blog/some-category/my-great-post/amp`.

Eventually, if I desactivate AMPforWP extension, the URLs (but blog home page) can't be reach, the server return an 500 error. Even if I activate the AMPforWP again.

---

## Here's what I have done so far

#### Ruby-on-Rails

*/config/routes.rb*

```
get '/blog' => redirect("https://www.example.com/blog/")
```

*/config.ru*

```
# https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy /^\/blog(\/.*)$/, 'http://example.wpengine.com$1', :username => 'example', :password => 'fakepwd', :timeout => 500, :preserve_host => true
end
```

#### WPEngine admin

*https://my.wpengine.com/installs/example/domains*

[image: WPEngine domains configuration for example blog]

#### Wordpress admin

*https://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php*

[image]

#### .htaccess configuration

*.htaccess*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN wtfdivi

# END wtfdivi
```

---

I'm stuck... :-(

Any help could be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been a while. I had the same setup, I have a rails application pointing to a WordPress blog as a "folder url" instead of a subdomain. Here is how I've solved it.

First, on reverse proxy I had to disable `preserve_host` so it would keep the domain on the request and not mess with my rules.

```
config.middleware.insert(0, Rack::ReverseProxy) do
  reverse_proxy_options preserve_host: false
  reverse_proxy %r{^\/blog(\/.*)$}, "#{Rails.application.config.blog_url}$1"
end
```

Then on my Wordpress I've moved the installation to a subfolder (named `blog`), instead of the root folder and used most of the default configuration of `.htaccess` as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope it still can help.